# mysqli_query works in phpmyadmin but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have looked for an answer for ages now, lots of similar questions but found no solutions yet...

Anyway, 
all I am trying to do is get the id of a user from the database using a mysqli_query, the query seems to work when I use it in phpmyadmin but doesn't when I use it as part of a php script.

```
$username = "bob";

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "user_data");

$sql1 = "select id from user_information where username='$username'";
$id = mysqli_query($db, $sql1) or die(mysql_error());

echo $id;
```

The database connection works fine, I am able to input data through php.

Any suggestions? (Anyone's help is greatly appreciated).

Comment: `$id` is a MySQLi resource, you need to fetch it first. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: And `or die(mysql_error());` won't give you anything, `mysql_` doesn't mix with `mysqli_`

Comment: If `$username` isn't going to be static in the future you should use parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't print the result from mysqli_query, it is mysqli_resource and for dumping the error you need to change mysql_error() to mysqli_error()

```
$username = "bob";
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "user_data");
$sql1 = "select id from user_information where username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    echo $row['id'].'<br>'; 
}
```